# How to turn off facebook synchronisation?

Tags: ios, star-wars-tiny-death-star

It seems like I made a mistake connecting my game to my facebook account. I don't feel a big need to have a backup all the time. So, there is a switch in the options, which, I suppose, allows you to stop this automatic synchronisation. But even though it is always on "off" in my TDS, it continues doing backups. How do I stop this? Will the "choose a backup" disappear after disable automatic backups?

Comment: I don't personally need this but I'm sure a bunch of people would appreciate some help... I know that you can usually log into FB and un-attach the game that way but I tried with mine and, either mine's not attached because the iOS version doesn't work properly (known bug), or it's not possible from that end.  Anyone with Android able to check?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would try - give it a shot.  Keep in mind it's possible doing this could destroy your game data completely, but I doubt it.

1. Log into Facebook.
2. Click the Settings gear in the top right.
3. Click the Apps category on the left, in the last section.
4. Select the game.
5. Click Remove App and remove the app.